# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Data must be an object

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, typescript, axios

error: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Data must be an object`

**Here is my JSON FILE [enter link to see my JSON file](https://pastebin.com/1juiRP4m)**

I can't start my json-server, because this REST API: gives me a JSON Array.
But I need a JSON Object to run json-server.
Is it possible to run json-server with JSON Array?

If so how please tell me ... what should i fix in my json file ?

```
npm json-server --port 3000 --watch db.json
```

fires this error message:

> Error: Data must be an object. Found object.See
> https://github.com/typicode/json-server for example.

**What should i make my JSON work with my JSON server?**

Comment: your `db.json` is not a valid JSON

Comment: Adarsh ​​Mohan I do not understand

Comment: take a look at the [module](https://github.com/typicode/json-server#module) methods in the documentation

Comment: Adarsh ​​mohan can you specifically point out the error?

Comment: You can only use objects when using the JSON server is its default way. But you can configure it to have json array and serve each json on each routes using the modules and custom routes mentioned in the documenation

Comment: you explain vaguely with an example, can't you show how it should look?

Comment: Adarsh
Json's parser in chrome ate it, maybe the problem lies elsewhere
so json is valid

Answer (score 0):

**correct JSON file**

[correct JSON file link here](https://pastebin.com/XqC4c2HT)

```
[1]: https://pastebin.com/XqC4c2HT
```

Answer (score 0):

Json object should be posted as below format:

```
   {
    "Posts":[
     {}, {}
     ]
   }
```